# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

I am tring to dynamically generate expression with Expression library in System.Linq. When i initialize the expression like this :

```
Expression<Func<WorkOrderView, bool>> expression = x => true;
```

and then implementation in where condition

```
await context.WorkOrderView.Where(expression).ToListAsync();
```

it works fine. And return all record in my related view. But if generating via using this class and method :

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, right.Body);
        var parameters = left.Parameters;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameters);
    }
}
```

and generating like this:

```
//END DATE
if (filterModel.EndDate is not null)
{
    temp = x => x.CreateDateTime <= filterModel.EndDate;
    expression = expression.AndAlso(temp);
}

//MATERIAL
if (filterModel.MaterialId != 0)
{
    temp = x => x.MaterialId == filterModel.MaterialId;
    expression = expression.AndAlso(temp);
}

//LINE 
if (filterModel.LineIds is not null && filterModel.LineIds.Count > 0)
{
    temp = x => filterModel.LineIds.Contains(x.LineId);
    expression = expression.AndAlso(temp);
}
///ETC. ETC.
```

it throws this error :

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Maybe you should print your final value of your expression `Debug.WriteLine(expression.ToString())`. What does it look like?

Comment: Assuming you are using this with EF (Core?)... why not just create a `WhereIf` extension on `IQueryable`, which I would expect to be more readable and probably better translatable, too?

Comment: Why are you using this code in the first place? Ever LINQ operation produces a *new* query, which means you can combine `Where` clauses with `if (condition) { query = query.Where(....);}`

Comment: In general, you can't just combine `Expression<Func<...>>` clauses because EF Core can't handle references to expressions inside other expressions. The problem and the solution are explained in the [LINQKit library docs](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#using-expression-variables-in-subqueries), using its `Expand()` method to expand nested `Expression<..>`s into an equivalent single Expression. LINQKit also provides the PredicateBuilder class that makes it easy to create and combine OR and AND conditions

Comment: @SomeBody it looks like this ```True && .Call ((.Constant<ABC.ABC.Web.Helpers.FilterHelper+<>c__DisplayClass0_0>(ABC.ABC.Web.Helpers.FilterHelper+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).filterModel).SegmentIds).Contains($x.SegmentId)
```

Comment: @SomeBody ı check with writing naturally and anatomy is correct which is normally result this : ```True && .Call (.Constant<ABC.ABC.Web.Controllers.ReportWorkOrderController+<>c__DisplayClass2_0>(ABC.ABC.Web.Controllers.ReportWorkOrderController+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).d).Contains($t.Id)```

Comment: @Fildor can you give me some sorurce how can ı and what is best practises for multiple conditional where clouses ?

Comment: Basically what Panagiotis wrote above. Like `if (filterModel.EndDate is not null)
{ query = query.Where(x => x.CreateDateTime <= filterModel.EndDate); }` And you can do this several times. It will be translated to "WHERE A and B and C ...". In our codebase, we added some extensions, that basically shortcut to `query.WhereIf( condition, filterclause)`. But that's "sugar".

Comment: @Fildor what is query type and what should be init value. I did not wrote before

Comment: I was assuming we are dealing with `IQueryable<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error has been explained by @PanagiotisKanavos in comments:

> In general, you can't just combine Expression<Func<...>> clauses because EF Core can't handle references to expressions inside other expressions.

To give you a way out, I would suggest to do this instead:

```
var query = context.WorkOrderView.AsQueryable();

//END DATE
if (filterModel.EndDate is not null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.CreateDateTime <= filterModel.EndDate);
}

//MATERIAL
if (filterModel.MaterialId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.MaterialId == filterModel.MaterialId);
}

//LINE 
if (filterModel.LineIds is not null && filterModel.LineIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => filterModel.LineIds.Contains(x.LineId));
}
///ETC. ETC.

return await query.ToListAsync(); // I'd pass a cancellationToken here ...
```

This will also translate to and-related sql filter expressions. (Like "... WHERE a AND b AND c ...")

Panagiotis also mentions different solutions, including the `PredicateBuilder` class which also gives you more options, for example to also have 'OR' conditions.

Comment: This make sense now

Comment: Is IEnumarable and IQueryable differences about getting data before where and after where clouses?

Comment: Depends. _Usually_, when you have an Enumarable, you are doing filtering on client-side. But we'd have to look at a specific example.

Comment: I want to filter in sql side filterin via Entity Framework. Is it possible with EntityFramework in this example with using IQuearable

Comment: Yes. All this will be translated into SQL and executed on the DB.